# Which is the best way to use database connection in phtml file in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, database, magento2.2.7, database-connection

Which is the best way to use database connection in phtml file in Magento 2

Only for fetching single result from the custom table table
because most of the time I am facing error like "User **mysql_user** already has more than '**max_user_connections**' active connections"
server guy not supporting me they told me to upgrade your server will upgrade the server later.

```
In ViewModel File 

<?php
namespace Satish\Addaction\Catalog;

class SqlConnection{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection
     */
    protected $resourceConnection;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
    ) {
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
    }

    /**
     * Get Table name using direct query
     */
    public function getTablename($tableName)
    {
        /* Create Connection */
        $connection  = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $tableName   = $connection->getTableName($tableName);
        return $tableName;
    }
}



in phtml file

<?php

$viewModel = $block->getViewModel();
$tableName = $viewModel->getTableName('custom_table');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $tableName;
/**
 * Execute the query and store the results in $results variable
 */
$results = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection()->fetchAll($query);
echo "<pre>";print_r($results);
```

Comment: the best way to use a db connection in a phtml file is to never use a db connection in a phtml file. Do this via view models https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/view-models.html

Comment: @Marius Please check